# Using both , and . as delimiter in scanner class

Tags: java

I have read all the already posted  questions but was unable to understand the syntax I know we have to use | but I don't know how to.
I have no idea of regex. So pls tell me the complete statement of the useDelimiter function of scanner class.

I was trying to separate a,b.c,d.e, into 
a
b
c
d
e 
Using next() of scanner class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument passed to `useDelimiter` is a regular expression.  So in this case, you can just use an expression like      `"[,.]"` which matches either `,` or `.`.

Comment: Inside character class delimiters, the `.` loses its metacharacter nature and is not a wildcard. The regex you suggest will match `,`, `\\`, or `.`. It should be simply `"[,.]"`. [Wow, I can't get the backticks to work properly in this comment.]

Comment: Oh, good point.  Thanks Ted, I'll fix it.   _invokes time machine_  There.  Fixed it.   And I don't think it would have matched backslash, because backslash doesn't lose its specialness inside `[]`, so this was actually correct, but slightly redundant.

Comment: Except you had doubled the backslash, which is how you escape a backslash and get it into the character class. :) But it's gone now, so all is good.

Comment: I did not double the backslash.  It was a string literal, so the extra backslash escaped it from the compiler, not from the regular expression.

Comment: D'oh. You're right. I always screw that up on the first attempt and forget that two levels of escape are needed.

Comment: (And yes, the Stack Overflow backticks suck badly when they get too close to backslashes).

Answer (score 1):

You can read entire `String` using `Scanner`. Then you will have some like following

```
 String str="a,b.c,d.e,";
```

Now you can use `replaceAll()` method to get what you want.

```
 String str="a,b.c,d.e,";
 System.out.println(str.replaceAll(",|\\."," "));
```

Out put:

```
a b c d e
```